Jenkinsfile multbranch pipeline prepare workspace directory permissions before docker agent is created
TLDR; I would like to run a bash script (to change the workspace filesystem permissions) before jenkins attempts to create the agent docker container and initializes the workspace (and fail if it doesnt have permissions), is there a way to do this without custom plugins?
This is my setup:

Host runs docker engine
Jenkins runs in a container inside the host, under user jenkins, and it has access to the docker engine by mounting the docker socket. Jenkins can run sudo commands without requiring password
I am defining a pipeline in a Jenkinsfile and I want a docker agent for my pipeline.
As per my understanding, I am running Docker in Docker via mounted socket so the workspace of my agent has to be a volume mounted in both the jenkins container and my agent's container, otherwise my agent container and the jenkins container will not be able to share a filesystem.
The volume is mounted in /opt/ in both containers and originally only root has access to this directory. Thus jenkins doesn't have permissions to create a workspace dir in here
I cannot change the configuration of the jenkins container and I cannot manually set the correct permissions in every jenkins container

This is my jenkinsfile:
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'jenkinsnode:latest'
            label 'many-nodes-label'
            customWorkspace '/opt/jenkins/'
            alwaysPull true
        }
    }
    stages {
       stage('Setup') {...}
       stage('Build') {...}
       stage('Test') {...}
    }
}

If I run it as is, then I get access denied as expected because jenkins will try to create the workspace directory and it doesn't have filesystem permissions: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /opt/jenkins/
How can I run a script on the node that has been assigned to the job, such that the jenkins container will run sudo chmod 777 /opt/ before it goes ahead with workspace creation?
I know that I can avoid defining the docker agent on the root level, so it'll run directly on the jenkins node and in the first step I can run commands to set the filesystem permissions, but then I get a complicated Jenkinsfile and into all sorts of problems:

I have to set the root level workspace to something that is not a volume, let's say /home/jenkins/
I successfully sets the right permissions on /opt/ in the first stage
Then I run the second stage with agent docker and reuseNode true, but that means reuse node and workspace so it attempts to mount /home/jenkins/ as a workspace into my agent container instead of passing --volumes-from. If I want to make this work I'd have to manually find the container id of jenkins and add the args parameter manually, but this gets more and more complicated and I'd like to avoid this.

Any ideas how to achieve this? I found the plugin "Pre SCM BuildStep" which could work but ideally I'd like to do this without new plugins
